# How to prevent text from iframe from being escaped in wysiwyg

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, wysiwyg

So, I'm building my wysiwyg text editor. I write in the iframe and the text is sent to a text area which then submits with the form. However, when sending the text from the iframe to the text area, the content gets escaped. I don't want it to, since I want HTML Purifier to filter the text, and I need to keep the brackets intact so that HTML Purifier removes them completely.The text shows in real time in the text area, but the ><& are instantly escaped. How can I prevent them from this?

Here is the Javascript that transfers the text from the iframe to the text area :

```
setInterval(function() {
var texte=$('#textEditor').contents().find('body').html().match(/ /g);
if(texte>=0){} else {
    $('#text').val($('#textEditor').contents().find('body').html());
}
$('#text').val($('#textEditor').contents().find('body').html());
}, 1000);
```

HTML

```
<iframe frameborder="0" id="textEditor" style="width:500px; height:300px; overflow:auto;"></iframe>
<form action="" method="post">
<textarea name="text" id="text" name="text" style="overflow:auto; display:none;" rows="6" cols="53"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```